# notepad++ / regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a data export like this:

```
""
abc
def
""
```

All lines which do not start with "" are part of the former line. So I need to remove the line break on all lines starting with "" and followed by a line not starting with "".

I can identify the lines without "" like this `^(?!"").+` But I have no clue how to do the rest.

Can you help?

Comment: So, what is the final result? Are there more of such items in the document? Also, how can you precise the trailing `""` context?

Comment: What should the output be in the example? `""abcdef`? Or something else?

Comment: what is expected output
""abcdef
""
or something else

Comment: Why use a regular expression? Just read all lines and merge them into one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:
Search:

```
^("")[^\r\n]*\K([\r\n]+)((^(?!""))[^\r\n]*)+
```

Replace:

```
$3
```

What the search does is: first finds a line starting with "", then matches any other symbols on that line, except new line (\r\n) (zero or more times). Then discards this match (\K) from the final result. Then it matches the new line and makes it part of the final result (so that we could remove it). 
After that it ensures that the next line doesn't start with "" and matches all characters except new line.

The regex might need further improvement.

Comment: Brilliant! I'll never get into regex. Luckily some people do. ;-)